# Adding a field to be indexed in apache solar

Tags: 7, search

I am new to drupal.

To add a field to be indexed in apache solar. I tried these two functions and its worked.

```
function filedepot_apachesolr_index_document_build_node(ApacheSolrDocument $document, $entity, $env_id) {
  $description_desc = $entity->description;
  $document->addField('sm_description_label', $description_label);
}

function filedepot_apachesolr_query_prepare(DrupalSolrQueryInterface $query) {
  $query->addParam('fl', 'sm_description_label');
}
```

This adds field "description_label" to be indexed in apachesolr (which i checked in the number of fields indexed in solr admin/reports/apachesolr/solr)

While indexing solr,reports showing stdclass::$description undefined property.

So i tried to check the properties of entity_type (file) using function entity_get_property_info('file'). It returned an array

```
 array(1) {
  ["properties"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["fid"]=>
    array(4) {
      ["label"]=>
      string(7) "File ID"
       ["type"]=>
      string(7) "integer"
      ["validation callback"]=>
      string(41) "entity_metadata_validate_integer_positive"
      ["schema field"]=>
      string(3) "fid"
    }

}
```

Hence entity_type 'file' doesnt contain description. How to add the description property to an entity_type ['field'].

The entity_type 'file' have fid property . How to access it inside apachesolr_index_document_build_node . when i tried to access $entity->fid inside apachesolr_index_document_build_node again it showing no property exists.

`Have to add a field to be indexed in apache solr. If the entity_type 'file' doesnt contain the field property,that has to be added to entity_type. How to do this.?`

Comment: As you've shown, the file entity doesn't have a description property, so `$entity->description` is invalid. It's more headache than it's worth to add properties to an existing entity (IMO), just use a field

Comment: The field is indexed now. I got that data also. But when searching it does not show any results.